# What are your common strategies/remedies when your new theory/idea stuck in most cases?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, soft-question, differential-topology, big-list, morse-theory

Sorry if this is not a suitable post for MO.

Sometimes after reading the origin of a theory/idea in differential topology I put myself in the shoes of that mathematician and ask myself, Did you do the same? Is that a natural theory/idea?

Let's explain my problem with an example.

When I read about Morse theory, first I thought that it is a natural and straight generalization of min-max theory of calculus and If I was Morse, it was quite natural to define a similar concept. Shortly after it came to my mind that oh, no this will not work in most cases. e.g. one can deform a manifold so that a critical point deforms to set of critical points e.g. south pole of sphere to a circle or just flatten the south pole of sphere.

and here (and in similar situations) [*although it is too soon to give up*] I conclude that oh no, this is not a good and applicable idea so I better forget it.

**Question:** What are your advices and your common remedies in similar situations? (except "don't give up"!)

---

**Edited:** To be a bit more focus, lets just talk about Morse theory. The following questions arise to my mind in similar situations and make me worry:

1. It is not applicable always
2. Always one can find a diffeomorphic manifold to given one such that the raw (my) Morse theory is almost meaningless (or should  I think its reverse? One can always find a diffeomorphic manifold to given one such that the raw (my) Morse theory is quite meaningful??)
3. In regard to (2), Do you recommend to follow promising questions instead of hopeless ones?

Comment: I think this is a great question in general, but probably too chatty for MO.

Comment: I think maybe this question could use a bit more focus -- I'm not sure I could say what constitutes a "similar experience" to the one described (similar in what respect? There are several aspects of the experience which are highlighted in the question body). That being said, when I have an idea that seems not to work, I often find it fruitful to think in detail about the simplest possible case where it doesn't work -- sometimes the example itself will suggest how to salvage the idea.

Comment: From Stanley's "How the Upper Bound Conjecture was proved," describing his initial dismissal of a fundamental construction: "I needed a ring whose Hilbert function had a certain relation to the f-vector of a triangulation of a sphere. It wasn't long before I realized that a certain graded algebra [...] would have the right Hilbert function. At that time I thought that this ring was too simple to be of use. In particular, the variety associated with such a ring is just a union of linear subspaces, hardly of great interest to algebraic geometers." (https://math.mit.edu/~rstan/papers/ubc.pdf)

Comment: A good question to ask yourself repeatedly is, "What am I trying to do? What do I really need?" Maybe what you unconsciously *think* you need isn't exactly what you really need. Real-life analogy: I went to the store to buy a blindfold to help me sleep better. They had no blindfolds. But I didn't leave immediately, and found elastic headbands that I thought might do. I now find that for my purposes, they work even better than most blindfolds.